# python pandas filter date column when date belongs to particular months

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How could i filter my df dataframe to only include data from April and May? Why does my last `in` statement fail? i want to filter data for April and May and copy it into another dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                       'month': [4, 3],
                       'day': [4, 5]})
x=pd.to_datetime(df)
4 in (4,5)
x.dt.month in (4,5)
#y=x.dt.month in (4,5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` checks whether the left operand is a member of the right operand, `x.dt.month` is a pandas series and not a member of `(4,5)`; You need the vectorized `isin` method:

```
x.dt.month.isin((4,5))
#0    False
#1    False
#dtype: bool
```

Comment: 1 second earlier, +1. Worth mentioning this is a good opportunity to use `set`.

Comment: @jpp could you share how to use `set`?

Comment: `vals = {4, 5}; mask = pd.to_datetime(df).dt.month.isin(vals)`

Comment: @Psidom, I'd question how vectorised `pd.Series.isin` actually is.. Combining `set` with `numpy` array usually means it's not (but please correct me).

Comment: @jpp Good question but actually if you look at `isin` [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.0/pandas/core/series.py#L3530-L3588), the values are always converted to an array before using `np.in1d`, which further uses `np.argsort` and vectorized comparison to calculate the result. So for numeric type, I'd say it's vectorized to some extent.